# Looking for a storage strategy for hybrid and full flash storage with manageable configuration overhead

Tags: ssd, performance, lvm

I have been using lvmcache with a larger HDD and an NVME drive (about one fifth of the size of the HDD) for a while for the space where I store my projects and data on my workstation at home, with encryption. So far nothing broke and I'm confident that I know enough to use LVM on servers and workstations. :-)

Going full flash will continue to be expensive for some time and replacing HDD and SSD with one large SSD is not what I have in mind designing a solution for my current storage needs regarding flexibility and reliability. So I will have HDDs but also add more SSDs until arrive at a full flash solution. Before I'm going to shoot myself in the foot or waste time on intricate details: Does anyone have experience with similar setups?

- OS, home and VMs will run on separate dedicated SSDs with LUKS+EXT4. Simple is best.
- Different content in the pool has different requirements:

  - My music or picture collection may have some, but little benefit from lvmcache. Could be uncached if space is needed.
  - Source code projects like compiling Android apps, OpenWrt or AOSP may benefit more from cache.
  - Some projects may require full flash and have redundant copies to be safe (RAID1 without actual requirement of involving RAID on entire disks, only LVs).
- RAID5 (or better RAID6) over the entire flash drives comes at the cost of less flexibility because of matching drive size requirement.

Is there a way to keep the configuration overhead to a more manageable level?

Stratis does not cover caching and RAID/redundancy at the moment. For btrfs someone would have to convince me that it improved in these areas recently. ZFS is only intended for my NAS setups at the moment. I'm open to suggestions.